# Error: cannot open (Directory of file) for writing, LNK1168

Tags: c++, linker-errors

```
#include <iostream>

float dis;
float time_;
float iv;
float acc = -9.8;
float value;

float getTime_(float disp, float iv_)
{
    if (iv_ == 0)
    {
        dis = -disp;
        time_ = sqrt((2 * dis) / acc);
        return time_;
    }
    else
    {
        dis = disp;
        time_ = (-iv_ + sqrt((((iv_ * iv_) * 1000) / 1000) + (19.6 * dis))) / 9.8;
        return time_;
    }
}

int main()
{
    value = 0;
    time_ = 0;
    iv = 0;
    dis = 0;

    float vod = 0.05; // insert displacement here in metres.

    value = std::round(getTime_(vod, iv) * 1000.0) / 1000.0;

    std::cout << value << " seconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

MY CODE, I'm not sure if this code will help but I cannot run my program properly, it fails to build as well. I have tried to do commands in cmd windows 10 to terminate the file since it was still running in the background, that worked but as soon as I changed one of the variables i my code, it went back to the error. Hopefully you can help me, error is in the title.

Comment: A previous build of your executable file is probably still running. You probably did not kill (all) running instances of that execuable file. I suggest that you open the Windows Task Manager (`CTRL`-`SHIFT`-`ESC`) to see how many instances of the executable file are still running, and kill them.

Comment: Do I need to add a .bat file to run those commands every time? if so then how?

Comment: I did kill everything using "taskkill /IM myfile.exe /F" in cmd. But every time I change a variable the error comes back.

Comment: Maybe your antivirus is the cause of your problems.

Comment: I agree that antivirus software can cause such problems. I have experienced it myself several times.

Comment: How can I remove it or stop it from effecting this then?

Comment: That would depend on what antivirus you are using.

Comment: Avira and I think the built-in windows one maybe

Comment: MSB3061 is another ERROR I got saying that the system is unable to delete the file and the access to the file is denied

Comment: Does the error disappear if you temporarily deactivate Avira?

Comment: I disabled my anti-virus then ran the cmd command and it seemed to have fixed itself

Comment: I'm all good now thx